# how to resolve getting syntax error at or near ":" Where clause

Tags: postgresql, repository-pattern, typeorm

I am new to coding and I am trying to develop new skills.

I am stuck at a point where I am trying to retrieve data based on a userid from PostgreSQL Task table.

I am using typeorm to achieve this
the following is my code

```
 async getTasks(
    getTasksFilterDTO: GetTasksFilterDTO,
    user: User,
  ): Promise<Task[]> {
    const { status, search } = getTasksFilterDTO;
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder('task');

    query.where('task.userId = : userId', { userId: user.id });

    const tasks = await query.getMany();
    return tasks;
  }
```

I am getting an error at line

```
query.where('task.userId = : userId', { userId: user.id });
```

the error is **[ExceptionsHandler] syntax error at or near ":" +736ms
QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near ":"**

```
at new QueryFailedError (C:\tutorials\nestjs-task-management\node_modules\typeorm\error\QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
at Query.callback (C:\tutorials\nestjs-task-management\node_modules\typeorm\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.js:176:38)
```

Can someone help me to understand the mistake I was doing?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `'task.userId = :userId'` so that `:userId` will be seen as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the space between `:` and `userId`:

```
query.where('task.userId = :userId', { userId: user.id });
```